# Make file not working when trying to compile casablanca code

Tags: makefile

My application has Casablanca usage for REST communication iam using it for first time . if i use simple line as below to compile no issues.

g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp x1.cpp x3.cpp x2.cpp -o myfile -lboost_system -lcrypto -lssl -lcpprest

but i tried to write a makefile(i am writing it for first time) for the above as below:

```
CXX      := g++
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11
LDFLAGS  := -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lboost_system -lcrypto -lssl -lcpprest
BUILD    := build
OBJ_DIR  := $(BUILD)/objects
APP_DIR  := $(BUILD)/apps
TARGET   := fdvdapp
INCLUDE  := -Iinclude/
SRC      := $(wildcard *.cpp)


OBJECTS := $(SRC:%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

all: build $(TARGET)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@ -c $<

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(APP_DIR)/$(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

.PHONY: all build clean

build:
    @mkdir -p $(APP_DIR)
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

clean:
    rm -rf build/*
```

the above make dosent seem to work i get errors undefined reference errors for all the libraries used.

what is wrong???

Comment: coorection to LDFLAGS  := -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lboost_system -lcrypto -lssl -lcpprest

Comment: Did you try to change this line `$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(APP_DIR)/$(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)`, i.e. move `$(OBJECTS)` before the `-o $(APP_DIR)` part? Maybe this helps ...

Comment: Could you also add the output of the errors? So we know, what your linker is complaining ...

Comment: are all your include files in the folder `include/` or are they in subfolders?